# Como obtener el numero de dias entre dos fechas de mongodb con nodejs

Tags: array, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, function

Tengo una base de datos en mongodb y una coleccion llamada reservacion, el caso es que tiene fechaEntrada y fechaSalida de tipo Date y necesito obtener el numero de dias entre ambos pero no sé cómo
intenté esto con momentjs  `var fecha1 = moment(reservacionEncontrada.fechaEntrada); var fecha2 = moment(reservacionEncontrada.fechaSalida); console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia');` pero me tira que moment is not defined, ya instalé el momentjs por npm

Answer (score 0):

parece que simplemente te falta importar la libreria de moment.

hazlo de esta manera:

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

he probado con una linea simple para comprobar:

```
var diferenciafechas = moment(moment().add(15, 'days')).diff(moment(), 'days');
console.log(diferenciafechas); // 15 (resultado por consola)
```